# Excel Select Case?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

i want to create the "cases" formula for excel to simulate Select case behavior (with multiple arguments and else optional).
If A1 and A2 are excel cells, this is the goal:

```
A1 Case:     A2 Formula:                                                                   A2 Result
5            cases({A1>5,"greather than 5"}, {A1<5, "less than 5"},{else,"equal to 5"})    equal to 5   
Hi           cases({A1="","there is nothing"},{else,A1})                                   Hi
1024         cases({5<A1<=10,10},{11<=A1<100,100},{A1>100,1000})                           1000
12           cases({A1=1 to 9, "digit"}, {A1=11|22|33|44|55|66|77|88|99, "11 multiple"})   (empty) 
60           cases({A1=1 to 49|51 to 99,"not 50"})                                         not 50
```

If it could, It must accept excel formulas or vba code, to make an operation over the cell before take a case, i.g.

```
cases({len(A1)<7, "too short"},{else,"good length"})
```

If it could, it must accept to or more cells to evaluate, i.g.

if A2=A3=A4=A5=1 and A1=2, A6="one", A7="two"

```
cases(A1!=A2|A3|A4|A5, A6}, {else,A7}) will produce "two"
```

By the way, | means or, != means different

Any help?

---

I'm grateful.

What I could write was this:

```
Public Function arr(ParamArray args())  'Your function, thanks
    arr = args
End Function

Public Function cases(arg, arg2)  'I don't know how to do it better
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        cases = .Choose(.Match(True, arg, 0), arg2)
    End With
End Function
```

I call the function in this way

```
=cases(arr(A1>5, A1<5, A1=5),arr( "gt 5", "lt 5", "eq 5"))
```

And i can't get the goal, it just works for the first condition, A1>5.

I fixed it using a for, but i think it's not elegant like your suggestion:

```
Function selectCases(cases, actions)
    For i = 1 To UBound(cases)
        If cases(i) = True Then
            selectCases = actions(i)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

---

When i call the function:

```
=selectCases(arr(A1>5, A1<5, A1=5),arr( "gt 5", "lt 5", "eq 5"))
```

It works.

Thanks for all.

---

After work a little, finally i get a excel select case, closer what i want at first.

```
Function cases(ParamArray casesList())
    'Check all arguments in list by pairs (case, action),
    'case is 2n element
    'action is 2n+1 element
    'if 2n element is not a test or case, then it's like the "otherwise action"
    For i = 0 To UBound(casesList) Step 2
        'if case checks
        If casesList(i) = True Then
            'then take action
            cases = casesList(i + 1)
            Exit Function
        ElseIf casesList(i) <> False Then
            'when the element is not a case (a boolean value),
            'then take the element.
            'It works like else sentence
            cases = casesList(i)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

When A1=5 and I call:

```
=cases(A1>5, "gt 5",A1<5, "lt 5","eq 5")
```

It can be read in this way: When A1 greater than 5, then choose "gt 5", but when A1 less than 5, then choose "lt 5", otherwise choose "eq 5". After run it, It matches with "eq 5"

Thank you, it was exciting and truly educative!

Comment: Why don't you just create a UDF (macro) in VBA that will use a Select Case statement to get the job done?

Comment: @Lance, the question as literally asked is kind of crazy, but I can see the motivation. It would be kind of useful to be able to define the case conditions as part of the formula. I gave an answer that doesn't go too far overboard but still satisfies that main goal.

Comment: In fact, that is my motivation! You are really smart!

Comment: Nice! See my edit for another version. There is also another little utility routine in there that you could use in your version to allow your UDF to return back range references as well as plain values. Well done!

Comment: Also, be careful with assumptions about array indices. I *think* paramarrays are always zero-indexed, but there might be an "Option Base" dependency involved. Array index "flexibility" is a huge pain in VBA. More about that at the bottom of this stackoverflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429965/handling-errors-in-math-functions/4432413#4432413

Comment: In fact, I did'nt understand what you meant in 2 last commentaries at all, what means "the back range references"? Hey! Thanks for all, master!

Comment: Range references are what you describe using Excel syntax like A1:Q42. When you pass one to an Excel UDF as a parameter, it shows up as a Range object. If you want to return a Range object from the UDF and not just the *value(s)* contained within, you have to do it explicitly with the VBA 'Set' keyword. I know, annoying! But sometimes you want the actual range, like when you've got a named formula that must evaluate to a range because it's used as the source for a validation list. And for array-index issues, see the linked stackoverflow answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

O.K., there's no way at all to do exactly what you want. You can't use anything other than Excel syntax within a formula, so stuff like 'A1 = 1 to 9' is just impossible.

You *could* write a pretty elaborate VBA routine that took strings or something and parsed them, but that really amounts to designing and implementing a complete little language. And your "code" wouldn't play well with Excel. For example, if you called something like

```
=cases("{A1="""",""there is nothing""},{else,A1}")
```

(note the escaped quotes), Excel wouldn't update your A1 reference when it moved or the formula got copied. So let's discard the whole "syntax" option.

However, it turns out you *can* get much of the behavior I think you actually want with regular Excel formulas plus one tiny VBA UDF. First the UDF:

```
Public Function arr(ParamArray args())
    arr = args
End Function
```

This lets us create an array from a set of arguments. Since the arguments can be expressions instead of just constants, we can call it from a formula like this:

```
=arr(A1=42, A1=99)
```

and get back an array of boolean values.

With that small UDF, you can now use regular formulas to "select cases". They would look like this:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(TRUE, arr(A1>5, A1<5, A1=5), 0), "gt 5", "lt 5", "eq 5")
```

What's going on is that 'arr' returns a boolean array, 'MATCH' finds the position of the first TRUE, and 'CHOOSE' returns the corresponding "case".

You can emulate an "else" clause by wrapping the whole thing in 'IFERROR':

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(MATCH(TRUE, arr(A1>5, A1<5), 0), "gt 5", "lt 5"), "eq 5")
```

If that is too verbose for you, you can always write another VBA UDF that would bring the MATCH, CHOOSE, etc. inside, and call it like this:

```
=cases(arr(A1>5, A1<5, A1=5), "gt 5", "lt 5", "eq 5")
```

That's not far off from your proposed syntax, and much, much simpler.

EDIT:

I see you've already come up with a (good) solution that is closer to what you really want, but I thought I'd add this anyway, since my statement above about bringing MATCH, CHOOSE, etc. inside the UDF made it look easier thatn it really is.

So, here is a 'cases' UDF:

```
Public Function cases(caseCondResults, ParamArray caseValues())
    On Error GoTo EH

    Dim resOfMatch
    resOfMatch = Application.Match(True, caseCondResults, 0)

    If IsError(resOfMatch) Then
        cases = resOfMatch
    Else
        Call assign(cases, caseValues(LBound(caseValues) + resOfMatch - 1))
    End If

    Exit Function

EH:
    cases = CVErr(xlValue)
End Function
```

It uses a little helper routine, 'assign':

```
Public Sub assign(ByRef lhs, rhs)
    If IsObject(rhs) Then
        Set lhs = rhs
    Else
        lhs = rhs
    End If
End Sub
```

The 'assign' routine just makes it easier to deal with the fact that users can call UDFs with either values or range references. Since we want our 'cases' UDF to work like Excel's 'CHOOSE', we'd like to return back references when necessary.

Basically, within the new 'cases' UDF, we do the "choose" part ourselves by indexing into the param array of case values. I slapped an error handler on there so basic stuff like a mismatch between case condition results and case values will result in a return value of #VALUE!. You would probably add more checks in a real function, like making sure the condition results were booleans, etc.

I'm glad you reached an even better solution for yourself, though! This has been interesting.

MORE ABOUT 'assign':

In response to your comment, here is more about why that is part of my answer. VBA uses a different syntax for assigning an object to a variable than it does for assigning a plain value. Look at the VBA help or see this stackoverflow question and others like it: [What does the keyword Set actually do in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349613/what-does-the-keyword-set-actually-do-in-vba)

This matters because, when you call a VBA function from an Excel formula, the parameters can be objects of type Range, in addition to numbers, strings, booleans, errors, and arrays. (See [Can an Excel VBA UDF called from the worksheet ever be passed an instance of any Excel VBA object model class other than 'Range'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596296/can-an-excel-vba-udf-called-from-the-worksheet-ever-be-passed-an-instance-of-any))

Range references are what you describe using Excel syntax like A1:Q42. When you pass one to an Excel UDF as a parameter, it shows up as a Range object. If you want to return a Range object from the UDF, you have to do it explicitly with the VBA 'Set' keyword. If you don't use 'Set', Excel will instead take the *value* contained within the Range and return that. Most of the time this doesn't matter, but sometimes you want the actual range, like when you've got a named formula that must evaluate to a range because it's used as the source for a validation list.

Comment: I tried your work and get what i want, but you suggest i could write a function that would bring the other worksheet functions. I'm guessing if you could write it for me please.

Comment: @jevchaviz, you're right. It's harder to "bring the MATCH, CHOOSE, etc. inside" than I originally thought. I'll post a longer explanation later, but the solution you came up with is a good one.

Comment: I didn't understand the usage of assign routine. Could you please put an example using values and range references, and its results please?