# Excel Select Case Type Mismatch Error

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a simple Select Case in Excel 2013.  I want the value in column R to be based on the value in column Q.  But I get a type mismatch error.  This is a shortened version of cases since, there are actually 20, but here is what I'm using to test (the following presents the type mismatch error):

```
Sub laranges()
Select Case Range("Q:Q").Value
    Case 0 To 0.49
    Range("R:R").Value= "Low"
    Case 0.5 To 0.99
    Range("R:R").Value= "Medium"
    Case Else
    Range("R:R").Value = "High"
End Select
```

End Sub

The following works if I change it to select only one cell (I have tested it on several cells and they were all successful individually):

```
Sub laranges()
Select Case Range("Q2").Value
    Case 0 To 0.49
    Range("R2").Value = "Low"
    Case 0.5 To 0.99
    Range("R2").Value = "Medium"
    Case Else
    Range("R2").Value = "High"
End Select
```

End Sub

Obviously I'm not referencing the ranges correctly.  I have also tried changing the range to Q2:Q3 and R2:R3, but I get the same error.  But if I reference Q2 and Q3 individually they run successfully.

How can I properly reference the ranges?  I have looked at [Ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/select-case.htm), [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221536(v=office.11).aspx), as well as several threads on SO but I just haven't been successful.

Comment: You can't grab `value` from more than 1 cell.

Comment: Well, you actually can grab more than a single cell's .Value or .Value2 but you end up with an array that cannot be dealt with as a single value. Loop through the values in Q2:Q<last populated cell> or deal with the average, mean, sum, etc.

Comment: What's going to happen if Q1 has ".3" and Q2 has ".99"?  What's your sub supposed to do in that case?? That's why there's a mismatch error.

Comment: @Jeeped oooo good to know!

Comment: @findwindow - It's done to load a range of cells' values into a variant array quite commonly.

Comment: lol yes. I have done that before XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate on the range

```
Sub laranges()
Dim sResult As String
For Each oCell In Range("Q:Q")
    Select oCell.Value
        Case 0 To 0.49
            sResult = "Low"
        Case 0.5 To 0.99
            sResult = "Medium"
        Case Else
            sResult = "High"
    End Select

    oCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = sResult
Next oCell
```

Putting this type of logic in the s/s itself would be much more efficient.

Comment: FWIW: I would find the last occupied cell in column Q, just so it does not iterate through 1M+ rows.  But yeah this is the gist of the issue.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to know.  It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this "formula" approach

```
Sub main()
' for "Choose" function clever use, see tobriand's answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488692/case-function-equivalent-in-excel

With ActiveSheet.Range("Q:Q").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Offset(, 1)

    .FormulaR1C1 = "=CHOOSE(   1   +   LOG(1 + (2*AND(RC[-1]>=0,RC[-1]<=0.49) ) + (4*AND(RC[-1]>=0.5,RC[-1]<=0.99)) ,2)," _
                     & "    ""High"" ,                 ""Low"",                          ""Medium"")"
    .Value = .Value

End With

End Sub
```