# Can a VBA custom function knows that the formula is entered as an array formula?

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to make the following function returns either multiple values or single value according to how the user enters formula?

```
Public Function Test(ByVal flNumber As Double) As Variant
  Dim flResult1 As Double
  Dim sResult2 As String
  Dim bArrayFormula As Boolean

  flResult1 = Round(flNumber / 10 ^ 6, 1)
  sResult2 = "million"

  ' How to know that the formula is entered as an array formula?
  If bArrayFormula Then
    Test = Array(flResult1, sResult2)
  Else
    Test = flResult1 & " " & sResult2
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: A good introduction ia available here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/returningarraysfromvba.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185089/excel-passing-array-to-user-defined-function-vba

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just examine *Application.Caller*

```
Public Function SmartFunction() As String
    addy = Application.Caller.Address
    If Range(addy).HasArray Then
        SmartFunction = "Array Formula"
    Else
        SmartFunction = "Normal Formula"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: @Gary's_Student - Thanks, I don't know about this one before.

Comment: @Astaroth  See VBA Help.................  lots of cool stuff available from *Application.Caller*